# Trying to install an apache website, but getting some weird endless errors

Tags: php, apache, github, content-management-system

https://github.com/kokspflanze/PServerCMSfull

^ I've been trying to install this website since 2 days, and I've done everything mentioned there properly, I dunno if I should do extra steps/modifications to the files. First, localhost was working fine but the when I surf localhost/pservercmsfull I see the directory files/folders but not the site content, a screenshot to explain what I meant: http://prntscr.com/7vuu4x

 Then I've checked httpd.conf again and found a typo, I've fixed it then localhost started saying the following; Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Thanks for reading, if you know any possible solution/something I should do but not mentioned in github, please let me know what is it and some hints to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set the DocumentRoot to the  public directory, that is the current problem.

i write this steps there https://github.com/kokspflanze/PServerCMSfull#step-3-configuration-for-apache

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to either rename 'init_autoloader.php' to 'index.php', or to create a new file called 'index.php' which consists of the following:

```
<?php include_once('init_autoloader.php'); ?>
```

In your Apache2 vhosts file, there is a parameter called 'DirectoryIndex' which defines which filename to render, if present, instead of showing the directory listing. More information on that can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/).